# Add JPA repository in reactive JHipster project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a JHipster project which is configured as a reactive project. I need to add JPA repository.

I changed this:

```
@Repository
public interface ActivePairsRepository extends R2dbcRepository<ActivePairs, Long>, ActivePairsRepositoryInternal {
    ....
}
```

to this:

```
@Repository
public interface ActivePairsRepository extends JpaRepository<ActivePairs, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ActivePairs> {
   ......
}
```

and I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But when I start the project I get:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-12-17 13:32:22.171","level":"WARN","message":"Registering converter from class java.util.BitSet to class java.lang.Boolean as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.","service":"Unknown","version":"Unknown","requestID":"Unknown","host":"test","data":{}}
{"timestamp":"2021-12-17 13:32:22.637","level":"WARN","message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activePairsService' defined in file [/Users/git/push/admin-console/target/classes/admin/console/service/ActivePairsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.nexo.repository.ActivePairsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}","service":"Unknown","version":"Unknown","requestID":"Unknown","host":"test","data":{}}
{"timestamp":"2021-12-17 13:32:22.688","level":"ERROR","message":"\n\n***************************\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\n***************************\n\nDescription:\n\nParameter 0 of constructor in io.console.service.ActivePairsService required a bean of type 'io.nexo.repository.ActivePairsRepository' that could not be found.\n\n\nAction:\n\nConsider defining a bean of type 'io.console.repository.ActivePairsRepository' in your configuration.\n","service":"Unknown","version":"Unknown","requestID":"Unknown","host":"test","data":{}}
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

I tried to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` but it's not working.

Comment: Is `ActivePairsRepository` in the same package where @springbootapplication is??

Comment: I tried also this but it's not working.